track if Alt Gr is pressed
I am trying to capture in python if the user pressed the Alt Gr but every time when the user press the Alt_Gr the system see that the user also pressed the Left CTRL.
I want to catch and make difference if the user pressed the Alt_Gr or/amd the Left CTRL, my code:
from pynput import keyboard

# Set to track if Alt Gr is pressed
alt_gr_pressed = False

def on_press(key):
    global alt_gr_pressed
    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_gr:
        alt_gr_pressed = True
        print(f'Special key {key} pressed')
    elif key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_l and alt_gr_pressed:
        # Ignore Ctrl_L if Alt Gr is pressed
        return
    else:
        try:
            print(f'Key {key.char} pressed')
        except AttributeError:
            print(f'Special key {key} pressed')

def on_release(key):
    global alt_gr_pressed
    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_gr:
        alt_gr_pressed = False
    print(f'Key {key} released')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:  # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()`

Thank you!

What specific behavior have you observed that led you to the conclusions you reached? Why do you think your program is detecting a left CTRL input? What would you expect to happen differently if the program was not detecting a left CTRL input?

On Windows, Alt Gr and Ctrl-Alt are equivalent by design, to support keyboards without the right Alt key.

If you run the provided script and you press the altgr it will write out that pressed both keys while if you press only the left ctrl it will write that.
Unfortunatelly Emilio you are right it looks like a design issue but I am hopeing that it is possible to do a workaround and detect it properly.
